# Conditional serialize property at runtime

Tags: .net, serialization

I want to have several types of serialization of the same object at runtime.
For example, i have class

```
class Car {
    string Color;
    string Model;
}
```

And I want one service to send only "color" property, and other one send only "model".
Is there any neat solution for this one?
Preferable with Newtonsoft Json.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an anonymous type:

```
var myObject = new Car();
return new { myObject.Color }
```

or

```
var myObject = new Car();
return new { myObject.Model }
```